# record game object movement use C# and windows form

Tags: c#, performance, character-encoding, windows-forms-designer

I have made a game use windows form ( C# programming) with 3 levels  , I need to know how can I record the game movement ?? that allowed click button show how the player was played????

Comment: What have you tried? How are you wanting to store it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to store all actions either in memory and on disk. For turn based or step like games (like card games or so) this can be achievable by having a action list defined up front and use that as input for your game controls.

In short this will result in a pattern like:

```
UX Action -> Game Action -> Execute Game Action
```

e.g.:

```
Arrow button press -> Translate to move instruction -> Apply move
```

This allows you also for easy playback. The UX action can be a click on a cell, or using your arrow keys etc.

If you have a more complex game, like Race games, first person shooters, things become a bit harder - you'll also need to store the exact time and duration of each game action.

These are the basics - If you want to know more, you'll need to be more specific.